# Unable to use helper in controller of laravel app

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-helper

I'm building an application, now i'm created a helper

```
class Students{
    public static function return_student_names()
    {
        $_only_student_first_name = array('a','b','c');
        return $_only_student_first_name;
    }
}
```

now i'm unable to do something like this in controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    class WelcomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('student/homepage');
        }
        public function StudentData($first_name = null)
        {
            /* ********** unable to perform this action *********/
            $students = Student::return_student_names();
            /* ********** unable to perform this action *********/
        }
    }
```

this is my helper service provider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        foreach(glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
            require_once($filename);
        }
    }
}
```

i event added it as an alias in config/app.php file

`'Student' => App\Helpers\Students::class,`

Comment: Any errors? Exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `use App\Helpers\Student;` at the top of your controller beneath the namespace delcaration:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\Student;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    // ...
```

Look more into PHP [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) and how they are used, I believe you may have a deficient understanding about them.  Their only purpose is to make so you can name and use two classes with the same name (e.g. `App\Helpers\Student` vs maybe `App\Models\Student`).  If you needed to use both of those classes inside of the same source file, you can alias one of them like this:

```
use App\Helpers\Student;
use App\Models\Student as StudentModel;

// Will create an instance of App\Helpers\Student
$student = new Student(); 
// Will create an instance of App\Models\Student
$student2 = new StudentModel();
```

You do *not* need to have a service provider for this, just the normal language features.  What you *would* need a service provider for is if you wanted to defer the construction of your Student object to the IoC:

```
public function register()
{
    $app->bind('App\Helpers\Student', function() {
        return new \App\Helpers\Student;
    });
}

// ...
$student = app()->make('App\Helpers\Student');
```

You should never have to `include` or `require` a class file in laravel because that is one of the functions that [composer](http://vegibit.com/composer-autoloading-tutorial/) provides.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a service provider to make it works. Just lets the Students class as you did:

```
class Students{
    public static function return_student_names()
    {
        $_only_student_first_name = array('a','b','c');
        return $_only_student_first_name;
    }
}
```

> all its methods should be static

You added the Facade correctly:

```
'Student' => App\Helpers\Students::class,
```

Finally, looks like your problem is caused by forgetting a backslash at facade name. Uses `\Students` instead of `Students`:

```
public function StudentData($first_name = null)
{
    $students = \Student::return_student_names();
}
```

> When using a facade, it is not necessary makes nay include, the facades were made to avoid complex includes in everywhere.

Comment: Why do you say that Service Worker is not needed? What do you think about this?
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-helper--cms-28537